# Type AdRequest cannot be resolved to a type Java

Tags: java, eclipse, project

I always have this problem when I import a project in to Eclipse:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where it says "enter image description here", you really should enter one. You have error messages mentioning that types and at least one package are not found. So, *where are they*?

Comment: Hi abouch92! When you get a chance, please edit the question and add your error messages.

Comment: You need to look at the 'Java Build Path' in the project properties and update it to tell Eclipse where to look for the missing classes.

Comment: hi nitind there is no messege says "enter image description here"

Comment: greg 449 i don't know how to update 'java Build Path' i try but i don't have any idea

Comment: Brandon Minnick i edit the question i add some errors